# How do I upload a FASTA file to R if it contains multiplexed data?

Tags: r, fasta, dna-sequence

I was hoping to use the seqinr method to upload FASTA files to R for analysis. However, they are multiplexed sequences.

```r
library(seqinr)

dnafile <- system.file("sra_data-3.fasta", package = "seqinr")
read.fasta(file = dnafile, as.string = TRUE, forceDNAtolower = FALSE)
```

This code states there are no `>` to read, but what's it is reading is this, which clearly has an arrow but also other text which I'm assuming is what it doesn't like.

```
'>' SRR573784.1.2 G3G26M402FVJLA length=74
TGTGAGTAGTACGGGCGGTGTGTGCCGTACCGTCAATTCCTTTAAGTTTCTGAGCGGGCTGGCAAGGCGCATAG
```

(Added quotations to show the arrow is there and prevent indent programming)

Any suggestions to upload this? I don't necessarily need to barcodes or anything, just a row for each sequence to be able to differentiate the sequences. Thank you for any ideas, multiplexed data is new to me.

```r
dnafile <- system.file("sra_data-3.fasta", package = "seqinr")
read.fasta(file = dnafile, as.string = TRUE, forceDNAtolower = FALSE)
```

Note only error occurs.

Comment: If you demultiplex the samples do they load into R individually? (e.g. using http://qiime.org/scripts/demultiplex_fasta.html or https://demultiplex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Unfortunately I am aiming to complete a tutorial on doing this solely in R. I otherwise would use qiime, yes, that's where I normally take multiplexes.

Comment: I have no idea sorry; probably best to ask the folks at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Update: dodging seqinr for initial input and simply using

```r
dnafile <- "file_name" 

DNAfile <- read.fasta(file = dnafile, as.string = TRUE, forceDNAtolower = FALSE)

length(SRAfile)
```

worked just fine.